# Syntax for partial parameters

Tags: dust.js

I cannot seem to get the syntax right for parameters to partials.  The following keeps getting a syntax error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Expected buffer, comment, partial, reference, section or special but "{" found dust.js line 60.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/static/js/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/static/js/dust.js'></script>
<body>
<p>TEST</p>
<p class='area1'>content_stuff</p>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  dust.loadSource(dust.compile("THE PARTIAL IS: {>inner foo='bar' /} AND THATS ALL", "outer"));
  dust.loadSource(dust.compile("INNERPART", "inner"));
  dust.render("outer", {}, function(err, out) {
    console.log(out);
    $(".area1").html(out);
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: actually i think i figured this out.  not 100% sure, but i believe that the 2 versions of dustjs (linkedin version and the other one) are different.  the non-linkedin one doesn't really support partial parameters but the linkedin one does.  as soon as i switched to the linkedin version of dust, the parameters worked ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick with the latest linkedin release. I think you may need double quotes around bar param value though.

Comment: yes i also discovered the hard way that double quotes make a difference over single quotes.